# How to find sql queries being executed from Oracle ADF Form

Tags: sql, oracle-adf

How can I find which query is being executed from an Oracle ADF 12c Form? We have ADF applications integrated with Oracle EBS 12.2 which make several calls to the database; I want to track the queries executed by these ADF forms. E.g., when I press a popup button a SQL query is executed from the backend, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Run your application with `-Djbo.debugoutput=console` java key and watch console output.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the ViewObjectImpl class and add a command to dump the query and its parameters to a special logger or the console.
The advantage over the debugoutput=console is that you do not get every debug message, and there are many of them.
You can look at https://blog.virtual7.de/adf-dump-query-and-all-vo-query-parameters/ how this can be done.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. But isn't there any way where I can search the query from Database. For example, when a query is executed from Oracle Applications (old Java Platform). I can get the SQL from the database SQL History table via session id. But that doesn't seem to work in ADF. I thought there might be some other way from extracting the executed SQL from database because normally the DB does keep a log of the SQLs called from other applications too

Comment: I'm sure there is such a possibility. For this, you should ask your DBA for help. He can activate tracing to get hold of all data you like to get. Getting the data via its session is tricky, as the sessions are not assigned per user but reused for different users. You can add information to the session which current user is using the session (see https://blog.virtual7.de/pass-user-and-applicationmodule-information-to-database-session/), but in the end you have to use some DB tracing to get the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You find all SQLs, including the ones executed from ADF pages in v$sqlarea, presumed they are not flushed out yet, so you should query this directly after SQL execution.
The easiest way to review this data would be in Excel through blitz report [DBA SGA SQL Performance Summary](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/dba-sga-sql-performance-summary/), where you would need to search for the module that your ADF pages use (presumably jdbc thin client). If you have a quiet environment to test, for example a development server, you can identify the most recently executed SQLs by last_active_time.